# How to Update from a Select using a Where statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm having a little problem trying to find the answer for this. I need to use an Update to put new info in some rows, using a Select with a Where statement.

In my main table I have the columns

```
Equipment_ID  Type  Unit_Name  Address  Latitude  Longitude
```

and in the aux table I have the updated Latitude and Longitude for each ID

```
Equipment_ID Type  Latitude Longitude
```

So I need to put the new Lat and Lon for each ID over the old Lat and Lon in the main table. I think something like this would work, but in this example I found in another question, he updates just one field and it confused me.

```
 UPDATE  a
 SET     a.marks = b.marks
 FROM    tempDataView a
   INNER JOIN tempData b
     ON a.Name = b.Name
```

How do I update the Latitude and Longitude, but having as a where statement, that updates only when

```
WHERE main.Equipment_ID = aux.Equipment_ID
AND   main.Type         = aux.Type
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `JOIN` in an update statement, you need to do the "join" in the `where` clause.

Also: do **NOT** repeat the target table in the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE  main
   SET latitude = aux.latitude, 
       longitude = aux.longitude
FROM aux
WHERE main.Equipment_ID = aux.Equipment_ID
AND   main.Type         = aux.Type
```

Comment: Well, technically, you *can* use `JOIN` in an `UPDATE`, just not to the table reference being updated.